# Serve virtuoso opensource behind a nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, virtuoso

I have a `virtuoso-opensource` instance on `localhost:8890`

I have configured a `nginx` proxy to redirect at `localhost/virtuoso`

```
location /virtuoso {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:8890/;
     proxy_set_header   Host localhost;
}
```

The main page of virtuoso is redirected but CSS and images are not. And when a go to `/virtuoso/conductor`, it redirect me to `/conductor`.

how can I properly configure `nginx` to get the right redirection?

Comment: I don't think guidance specific to `nginx` exists (yet), but perhaps the docs for doing this via `apache` will work for you?  [Standlone](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSetApacheVirtuosoPortNumber) or as part of the [product manual](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/virtdir/#apachedoingproxy)...

Comment: Possibly part of [this doc](https://harshp.com/dev/guides_tutorials/semantic-web/setting-up-openlink-virtuoso/#exposing-virtuoso-interfaces-using-nginx) will also be helpful... Please let me know?